# Orchard CMS for different presentation layer, is it possible?

Tags: orchardcms

We are looking at several CMS systems, and narrow down to Orchard CMS as one of the option due to the great flexibility + the editor is "Bootstrap" friendly.

One of the very main concern though is that our project (multi-tenancy) is already setup in its own architecture (DDD), so it had its own Presentation Layer. My question is:

- Can we hook up our presentation layer to Orchard Database and pulling content from there? Not sure if that is the best way because looks like Orchard's Presentation Layer has it own view rendering mechanism to take into account of zones, widgets, shapes etc.
- If not, are there better ways to do this? Or do we have to use Orchard Presentation Layer as ours?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys.

P.S On side note, any layout editor tools similar to the one in Orchard CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. There are sites out there, such as Halo Waypoint, that are built that way. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csd0Z3hHDDw for a presentation about this.

The difficulty here may be to spin up the Orchard content manager from your existing infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks a ton. The clip is super helpful and pointing us to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pulling data from Orchard database is possible. Please have a look at the well written article from Sebastien Ros: http://sebastienros.com/understanding-orchard-s-database

Comment: Thank you. We were able to query the DB in a similar way, but we want to figure out if there is a better way. the clip that @Bertrand point out helped us.